# Cost of Preimage attack

Tags: cryptography, md5, hash

I need to know the cost of succeeding with a Preimage attack ("In cryptography, a preimage attack on a cryptographic hash is an attempt to find a message that has a specific hash value.", Wikipedia).

The message I want to hash consists of six digits (the date of birth), then four random digits. This is a social security number.

Is there also a possibility to hash something using a specific password. This would introduce another layer of security as one would have to know the password in order to produce the same hash values for a message.

I am thinking about using SHA-2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know how expensive it is to find a preimage for the string you're describing, you need to figure out how many possible strings there are. Since the first 6 digits are a date of birth, their value is even more restricted than the naive assumption of 10^6 - we have an upper bound of 366*100 (every day of the year, plus the two digit year).

The remaining 4 'random' digits permit another 10^4 possibilities, giving a total number of distinct hashes of 366 * 100 * 10^4 = 366,000,000 hashes.

With that few possibilities, it ought to be possible to find a preimage in a fraction of a second on a modern computer - or, for that matter, to build a lookup table for every possible hash.

Using a salt, as Tom suggests, will make a lookup table impractical, but with such a restricted range of valid values, a brute force attack is still eminently practical, so it alone is not sufficient to make the attack impractical.

One way to make things more expensive is to use iterative hashing - that is, hash the hash, and hash that, repeatedly. You have to do a lot less hashing than your attacker does, so increases in cost affect them more than they do you. This is still likely to be only a stopgap given the small search space, however.

As far as "using a password" goes, it sounds like you're looking for an [HMAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hmac) - a construction that uses a hash, but can only be verified if you have the key. If you can keep the key secret - no easy task if you're assuming the hashes can only be obtained if your system is compromised in the first place - this is a practical system.

Edit: Okay, so 'fractions of a second' may have been a slight exaggeration, at least with my trivial Python test. It's still perfectly tractable to bruteforce on a single computer in a short timeframe, however.

Comment: I'm not familiar with social security #'s in USA, but I imagine them to be fairly easy to generate every possible permutation of them.  This creates a unique problem for this question because given a set of all possible security numbers (which I assume is easily calculable) and given a database of hashed numbers and salts, it would be reasonably easy for a home computer to calculate all the social security numbers for each record.  Multiple hash layers would help definatly, but the data we are storing makes this problem a bit harder and I'm not sure what the best way to store them would be.

Comment: Also multiple layers of hashing starts to become security through obscurity.  It's an interesting problem and I'm not sure how I would go about storing data such as this.

Comment: If you store a hashed password in the user records, you could use the raw password as the salt for the social security number.  This would then mean the social security # could not be derived unless the raw password for the account was known.  (However you will run into problems when users wish to change their password.)

Comment: @Tom It's not a unique problem: ATM PINs suffer the exact same issue, only with an even more restricted search space. Salts do make assembling a database impractical - just choose a salt that's long enough for the purpose. And iterated hashing isn't security through obscurity - no obscurity is involved.

Comment: Finally, why cook up exotic salting schemes? They're certain to be no more secure (and probably less so) than using a purely random per-value salt. As I've already pointed out, though, with a keyspace so small, salting alone will not suffice.

Answer (score 2):

SHA-2, salts, preimage atttacks, brute forcing a restricted, 6-digit number - man it would be awesome if we have a dial we could turn that would let us adjust the security.  Something like this:

```
Time to compute a hash of an input:
 SHA-2, salted                                Better security!
  |                                            |
 \|/                                          \|/
 |-----------------------------------------------------|
.01 seconds                                           3 seconds
```

If we could do this, your *application*, when verifying that the user entered data matches what you have hashed, would in fact be a few seconds slower.

But imagine being the *attacker!*

> Awesome, he's hashing stuff using a salt, but there's only 366,000,000 possible hashes, I'm gonna blaze through this at 10,000 a second and finish in ~10 hours!
>
> Wait, what's going on!  I can only do 1 every 2.5 seconds?!  This is going to take me 29 years!!

That would be awesome, wouldn't it?

Sure would.

I present unto you: [scrypt](http://www.daemonology.net/blog/2009-05-09-scrypt-key-derivation.html) and [bcrypt](http://chargen.matasano.com/chargen/2007/9/7/enough-with-the-rainbow-tables-what-you-need-to-know-about-s.html).  They give you that dial.  Want to spend a whole minute hashing a password?  They can do that.  (Just make sure you remember the salt!)

Comment: A minute today. 30 seconds in 18 months, and 15 seconds in 36. ;) Thanks for linking to the specific schemes, though.

Comment: Actually password hashing schemes have been doing this for years  (hashing 500 times so it costs more for the attacker). Unfortunately things like rainbow tables (hellman time memory tradeoffs) negate a lot of this computation on the attackers side as they build lookup tables by running the hash on it's own output n times.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure what your question is exactly, but to make your encrypted value more secure, use [salt](http://j2eeforum.blogspot.com/2010/03/how-to-use-salted-md5-hash-for-securing.html) values.

Edit: I think you are sort of describing salt values in your question.

Comment: "four random digits" looks like salt

Comment: The message I want to hash is a social security number, as this is sensitive data, and should not be stored.

Comment: You should definatly hash it alongside a salt value then, as such a restricted lexicon as a social security number would be extremely vulnerable to a dictionary attack.